# Monoid instance resolution of `Int -> Int -> Ordering`

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I plan to showcase an example of the power of typeclasses in a small intro I'll give to Haskell tomorrow.

I thought I'd double check on what I was going to present because I'm not 100% confident.

So, let's say I have two functions:

```
firstSort :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
firstSort a b = compare (even a) (even b)

secondSort :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
secondSort = compare
```

Now, I can combine those two sorts thanks to their Monoid instances:

```
sort :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
sort = firstSort <> secondSort
```

Now what I'd like to confirm is the process used during the `mappend` of the two sorts.

From what I understand, it works this way:

- first the instance:

  ```
  instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
          mempty _ = mempty
          mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
  ```

  is used. This is done by instanciating the `a` of this instance with `(Int -> Int)`. Also, the declaration of `mappend` got me puzzled for some time since it takes 3 arguments instead of 2 but then I remembered that `(a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b)` is actually the same as `(a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> a -> b`.

  Thanks to this instance we obtain that `firstSort <> secondSort` is:

  ```
  \a b -> (firstSort a b) <> (secondSort a b)
  ```
- then the instance:

  ```
  instance Monoid Ordering where
          mempty         = EQ
          LT `mappend` _ = LT
          EQ `mappend` y = y
          GT `mappend` _ = GT
  ```

  is used with the specified `mappend` on the results of `firstSort` and `secondSort`

So, to sum it up, it would match the `Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)` instance with `b = Ordering` and `a = (Int -> Int)` and afterwards the `Monoid Ordering` instance.

Is that correct?

Comment: Please don't downvote without a comment so that I can improve the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You've concluded correctly.

Since `Int -> Int -> Ordering` is curried, it can be seen as a function of one argument, which returns another function. I.e.:

```
Int -> (Int -> Ordering)
```

Hence the compiler resolves the `Monoid` instances in three steps:

```
 Value Type               | Monoid Instance
--------------------------|---------------------------
 Int -> (Int -> Ordering) | instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
 Int -> Ordering          | instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
 Ordering                 | instance Monoid Ordering
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's see. I don't think the `a` that you want is `(Int -> Int)` because function types associate to the right when there are no parantheses. In your case, the types are

```
firstSort :: Int -> (Int -> Bool)
secondSort :: Int -> (Int -> Bool)
```

So, something interesting is going on here. When you concatenate the two functions, it's actually doing it twice! First, the `a` is just the first `Int` and `b` is the `Int -> Bool`, so we have to use the Monoid structure of `Int -> Bool`. But to do that we have to do the exact same thing again, so the `a` is `Int` and the `b` is `Bool`.

```
firstSort <> secondSort = \a -> (firstSort a) <> (secondSort a) 
                        = \a -> (\b -> (firstSort a b) <> (secondSort a b))
```

But the end result is still the same as the one you derived:

```
                        = \a b -> (firstSort a b) <> (secondSort a b)
```